# Please merge [angular] into [angularjs]

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

Please merge [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) into [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs), or make them synonyms.

- [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) is used from 316 questions.
- [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) is used from 960 questions.

The software library is [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/).

Comment: [Angular displacement on canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908224/angular-displacement-on-canvas) has nothing to do with this library but has this tag.

Comment: @KevinVermeer does it actually serve any helpful purpose on that question? I don't see one...

Comment: @BenBrocka - Not really, [tag:math] and [tag:formula] by themselves are perfect for that question.

Comment: Bumping this up. ***angular*** has 316 now, and ***angularJS*** has 960. Both refer to *AngularJS* framework in their wiki info.

Answer (score 4):

Using `angular` for question about [the Javascript framework](http://angularjs.org/) is wrong, since the correct name is "AngularJS".

So the `angular` questions should be moved to `angularjs`, regardless of which tag has more questions in it, and `angular` should be removed (or, if kept, have its description changed).